# Uploading file without any external gem rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

After viewing rails guide 4 [guides.rubyonrails.org/v4.0.6/form_helpers.html](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/v4.0.6/form_helpers.html). I am trying to upload image without any gem, but when hit create button, my picture field is empty.

Here is my Controller :

```
class ImagesController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_image, only: [:show, :edit,:upload, :update, :destroy]

  # GET /images
  # GET /images.json
  def index
    @images = Image.all
  end

  # GET /images/1
  # GET /images/1.json
  def show
  end

  # GET /images/new
  def new
    @image = Image.new
  end

  # GET /images/1/edit
  def edit
  end

  # POST /images
  # POST /images.json
  def create
    @image = Image.new(image_params)
    if params[:image].present?
      file = params[:image][:picture]
      File.open(Rails.root.join('app','assets', 'images', file.original_filename), 'wb') do |f|
        f.write(file.read)
      end
    end

    respond_to do |format|
      if @image.save
        format.html { redirect_to @image, notice: 'Image was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render action: 'show', status: :created, location: @image }
      else
        format.html { render action: 'new' }
        format.json { render json: @image.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # PATCH/PUT /images/1
  # PATCH/PUT /images/1.json
  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @image.update(image_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @image, notice: 'Image was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { head :no_content }
      else
        format.html { render action: 'edit' }
        format.json { render json: @image.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /images/1
  # DELETE /images/1.json
  def destroy
    @image.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to images_url }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

#file upload

  def upload
    uploaded_io = params.require(:image).permit(:picture)
    File.open(Rails.root.join('public','uploads',uploaded_io.original_filename), 'wb') do |file|
      file.write(uploaded_io.read)
    end
  end


  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_image
      @image = Image.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def image_params
      params.require(:image).permit(:name)
    end
end
```

Here is my _form.html.erb file:

```
<%= form_for(@image) do |f| %>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :name %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :name %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :picture %><br>
    <%= f.file_field :picture %>
  </div>
  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

My route file:

```
Imageupload::Application.routes.draw do
  resources :images
end
```

My schema.rb file:

```
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 20140725043842) do

  create_table "images", force: true do |t|
    t.string   "name"
    t.string   "picture"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
  end

end
```

Here is my show.html.erb file:

```
<p id="notice"><%= notice %></p>

<p>
  <strong>Name:</strong>
  <%= @image.name %>
</p>

<p>
  <strong>Picture:</strong>
  <%= image_tag @image.picture %>
</p>

<%= link_to 'Edit', edit_image_path(@image) %> |
<%= link_to 'Back', images_path %>
```

What's wrong? or you can tell me how can I upload file without any external gem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> :multipart => true

is missed out.

Add it up like

```
<%= form_for @image, {},:html => {:multipart => true } do |f| %>
```

[Uploading Files](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/v4.0.6/form_helpers.html#uploading-files) it says

> If you use `form_for`, this is done automatically -- **"multipart/form-data"**

not tried.

Comment: image are uploaded to /assets/image dir but its not showing when i call that image ( show.html.erb)

Comment: I think answer to the actual Question is answered. You can ask a different question on how are you trying to display images with `code`

Comment: dear nithin, need your help. [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25364093/uploading-image-or-file-in-ruby-on-rails-4)

Comment: Hmmm.... Now i need your answer. Thats working when i call that by individual url. Like <%= image_tag '/public/tea.jpg' %>    but i need <%= image_tag @image.picture  %>   plz, i know you can do that.

Comment: are you using any gem to upload? If not, store url path in picture attribute

Comment: I am not using any gem for upload.

Comment: Plz , give me a proper way to do that, i spent a lot of time but every time i failed.

Comment: before `@image.save`, set `@image.picture = "/public/'#{file.original_filename}'"`

Comment: ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/public/images/photo%20sun.jpg")

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/59627/discussion-between-nithin-and-mezbah).