# uploading image or file in ruby on rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

Here, I want a clear concept about uploading file or image without using any gemfile(Ex: peperclip, carrierwave etc).

Previously, I did some work. Where i can upload images in "/assets/images" folder.  But i could't see images when i call it in my show page(there was only a placeholder of break image).
here is the screenshot of show page:

[image: screenshot of show page]

how can i show those images in my show.html.erb file?

Here is my ImagesController.rb file:

```
class ImagesController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_image, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  # GET /images
  def index
    @images = Image.all
  end

  # GET /images/1
  def show
  end

  # GET /images/new
  def new
    @image = Image.new
  end

  # GET /images/1/edit
  def edit
  end

  # POST /images
  def create
    @image = Image.new(image_params)
    if params[:image].present?
      file = params[:image][:picture]
      File.open(Rails.root.join('app','assets', 'images', file.original_filename), 'wb') do |f|
        f.write(file.read)
      end
    end

    respond_to do |format|
      if @image.save
        format.html { redirect_to @image, notice: 'Image was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render action: 'show', status: :created, location: @image }
      else
        format.html { render action: 'new' }
        format.json { render json: @image.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end

    end
  end


  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @image.update(image_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @image, notice: 'Image was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { head :no_content }
      else
        format.html { render action: 'edit' }
        format.json { render json: @image.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /images/1
  def destroy
    @image.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to images_url }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_image
      @image = Image.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def image_params
      params.require(:image).permit(:name)
    end
end
```

Here is my show.html.erb file:

```
<p><%= @image.name %></p>

<p><%= image_tag @image.picture %></p>
```

Here is my schema.rb file:

```
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 20140725043842) do

  create_table "images", force: true do |t|
    t.string   "name"
    t.string   "picture"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
  end

end
```

please tell me, if you need more information about my project.
please give me some advice. I want a clear understand about uploading image/file and show them without using gemfile.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to upload images to a folder that doesn't need precompiling to be show, as assets do. Try uploading them to `public` folder.

Also you might want to read about the asset pipeline and why aren't they displaying:

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html